# MySQL multiple ORDER BY conditions with limit for each condition

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine

I have the entity `Product` (mapped to the table `product`) with the following fields:

- createdAt (creation date)
- numberOfLikes (number of received likes)
- numberOfComments (number of received comments)

I need to create a paginated dashboard with **20 elements in each page** (and no duplicates). Right now I am doing 3 different queries to extract and then combines the following items in a single list:

- top 10 most recent products (ORDER BY createdAt DESC)
- top 5 most liked products (ORDER BY numberOfLikes DESC) <== I am manually excluding the IDs from the first query with a `WHERE id NOT IN`
- top 5 most commented products (ORDER BY numberOfComments DESC) <== I am manually excluding the IDs from the first and the second query with a `WHERE id NOT IN`

I would like to **create a single query** to extract all the 20 previous items. Is it possible?

I am using MySQL with Doctrine (Symfony) and I would be interested in a **Doctrine-compatible solution**.

Comment: Have you tried using a [UNION](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html) (not sure if Doctrine supports it).

Comment: Unfortunately the `UNION` operator isn't supported by Doctrine but that's not the main problem. If the second list contains elements from the first list, doesn't the UNION remove the duplicates thus having less than 20 items in total? Thanks @NigelRen!

Comment: You have both UNION DISTINCT and UNION ALL.

Comment: But with UNION DISTINCT I would have less than 20 items, with UNION ALL I would have duplicates right? I would like exactly 20 items but with no duplicates.

Comment: ' If the second list contains elements from the first list, ' - How would that happen you would still be using not in..(or not exists).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to do it in a single query. I would use a combination of array methods, if the number of total posts is limited (like only 100 posts are visible in the dashboard).

Answer (score 0):

This requires using `UNION`, which means you can't have a Doctrine-compatible solution.

The core methodology would be the same as what you're doing at the application level, except uglier.  To get the exact same behavior, you would have to do something like

```
SELECT [text of first query]
UNION
SELECT [text of second query]
WHERE `id` NOT IN (
  SELECT `id` FROM (SELECT [text of first query])
)
UNION
SELECT [text of third query]
WHERE `id` NOT IN (
  SELECT `id` FROM (SELECT [text of first query])
)
AND `id` NOT IN (
  SELECT (SELECT `id` FROM [text of second query])
)
```

This means that the first query gets executed three times, independently, and the second query gets executed twice.